# SQL Join multiple tables to one view

Tags: sql

What i'm trying to do is get data from several tables (+50) and make this available in a general view.

The "ObjNr" column can exist several times in each table, so I want to get the record with the latest timestamp.

See this link for a better explanation of my problem including the source tables and the desired result:

[image: Database overview]

I have tried several scenarios like unpivoting,..., using c# to do this in the background, ... but i'm really curious what the best way would be to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 50+ similar tables? This looks like a very bad data model. Why is this not one table?

Comment: You should tag SQL questions always with the DBMS you are using. I have posted a standard SQL answer, but DBMS are only standard-compliant up to a point. Some don't support `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Looking at this structure, my guess is it may be tied to an external system (ERP system perhaps?).  With situations like this, you're usually at the mercy of whatever the system has.  Building out views is the best solution really.

Comment: tables are not similar, for the example's sake I used similar tables. Thanks for the quick answer Thorsten. Trying it out now. @user2366842, absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rank your rows with `ROW_NUMBER`. Then apply `UNION ALL`.

```
select
  id, objnr, objname, datetime, batchnr, batchnr_component_name
from
(
  select
    id, objnr, objname, datetime, batchnr, batchnr_component_name,
    row_number() over (partition by objnr order by datetime desc) as rn
  from table1
  union all
  select
    id, objnr, objname, datetime, batchnr, batchnr_component_name,
    row_number() over (partition by objnr order by datetime desc) as rn
  from table2
  union all
  select
    id, objnr, objname, datetime, batchnr, batchnr_component_name,
    row_number() over (partition by objnr order by datetime desc) as rn
  from table3
  union all
  select
    id, objnr, objname, datetime, batchnr_2, batchnr_2_component_name,
    row_number() over (partition by objnr order by datetime desc) as rn
  from table3
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```